# Can't run chkdsk on external HDD after bad unmount

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, mount

I was transferring data to my external when I accidentally unplugged it. Now it won't mount correctly. I think I just need to have windows recognize and fix the bad unmount, but I can't get chkdsk or disk management or anything to recognize the drive.

When I plug it in, it shows up in "my computer" as E:, but does not show the volume's name or size. If I right click it, the "my computer" window freezes.

If I go to diskmgmt, E: doesn't show up.

If I do to cmd and type E: or cd E: the cmd window hangs forever until I unplug the drive. It also does this if I do chkdsk /f E:

I am confident there is no physical damage to the drive and it's in working condition, it's just not mounting correctly. How can I get chkdsk to run on this drive?

Comment: If it doesn't show up in Disk Management, it is more serious than just some data error, because even an unformatted drive should be visible. Can you find it in Command Prompt? And what is the drive to computer interface? SATA to USB, such as external USB case? Perhaps the interface board is broken?

Comment: Try to right-click the drive in Explorer and choose "Format..."

Comment: @user3169 It's an external USB, and probably SATA inside the enclosure. If I try to change to its directory in command prompt it freezes

Comment: @harrymc right clicking it in explorer causes the window to freeze, and the right click menu does not pop up.

Comment: I think to find out you will have to swap something (the USB bridge, the drive or the computer). Also the USB cable if you haven't tried another one yet.

Comment: It's definitely not the cable, PC, or USB port as I've tried using different computers, USB ports etc. maybe the drive itself is messed up physically, but that seems unlikely